# How to show Numeric keyboard while entering in textfield?

Tags: 7, forms

I am creating a custom form field with text-field type. That will accept only numbers, so I want to display only numeric keyboard instead of alphanumeric keyboard. How can I achieve that?

I tried using `Elements` module but I don't want to use extra features of this module.So I am searching for code snippet. Is there any way to do it in a custom way?

Comment: You have to set the input type to 'number'. eg: `<input type="number" ... />`

Comment: @Jaypan, Thank u but I am doing this via Form api. So i dont have type=number in form api.

Comment: I believe you can use this module for that: https://www.drupal.org/project/elements

Comment: I have mentioned that in question only. I dont want to use that one.

Comment: Ok, I'll put the answer below then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create a module named html5_form_element. Then you need to set up the following

Implement hook_element_info() to tell Drupal about your element type:

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_element_info()
 */
function html5_form_element_element_info()
{
  $types['number_input'] = array
  (
    '#input' => TRUE,
    '#theme' => 'number_input',
    '#theme_wrappers' => array('form_element'),
  );

  return $types;
}
```

Next implement hook_theme() to define the theme for your input type:

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_theme()
 */
function html5_form_elements_theme()
{
  $theme = array
  (
    'number_input' => array
    (
      'render element' => 'element',
    ),
  );

  return $theme;
}
```

And finally, create the theme function that will theme your element:

```
function theme_number_input($variables)
{
  $element = $variables['element'];
  $element['#attributes']['type'] = 'number';
  element_set_attributes($element, array('id', 'name', 'value', 'size', 'maxlength'));
  _form_set_class($element, array('form-number'));

  $extra = '';
  if ($element['#autocomplete_path'] && !empty($element['#autocomplete_input']))
  {
    drupal_add_library('system', 'drupal.autocomplete');
    $element['#attributes']['class'][] = 'form-autocomplete';

    $attributes = array();
    $attributes['type'] = 'hidden';
    $attributes['id'] = $element['#autocomplete_input']['#id'];
    $attributes['value'] = $element['#autocomplete_input']['#url_value'];
    $attributes['disabled'] = 'disabled';
    $attributes['class'][] = 'autocomplete';
    $extra = '<input' . drupal_attributes($attributes) . ' />';
  }

  $output = '<input' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . ' />';

  return $output . $extra;
}
```

Clear your caches, and you can now use `'#type' => 'number_input'` in the Form API.

Comment: Is this mandatory to create module with the name which you suggested or i can copy this code in my existing module? Where I need to put this theme function? I tried by keeping this in template.php but this function not calling while executing. Help me regarding this.

Comment: You'll need to create a module, I don't think this can be done in a theme. Elements need to be module based.

Comment: Thank you its working, but is there any way that i can remove uppper/lower arrows coming by default to that field.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know that. It's a separate question to this one, so you'd be best starting a new thread. That said, it's not a Drupal question, it's an HTML question, so Drupal Answers probably isn't the right place to ask.

Comment: Hi, I did everything and checked in android its not showing numeric keypad fr that particular field. I tried by adding $element['#attributes']['inputmode'] = 'numeric'; also but no success. Any other ways u know??

Comment: Its coming buddy. I was doing some mistake. thanks

Comment: I'm glad to hear that.